# Prevent empty PartitionKey in CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I wanted to prevent any document create/update in Cosmos db with empty or null `PartitionKey`. Is this possible from a db level?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it is not possible to enforce this constraint from the database level. You would need to implement this from the application side only.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection is setup with a partition key, I don't see how you can update it using any SDK without specifying it because how would CosmosDB know in what partition to put it?

Of course if you create a null partition key that is a different story.